# Use of the Term "Topological Invariance" in Lee's Introduction to Smooth Manifolds

Tags: manifolds, manifolds-with-boundary

I'm reading through Lee's *Introduction to Smooth Manifolds*, and Theorem 1.37, which asserts that the interior and boundary of a manifold with boundary are disjoint, is titled "Topological Invariance of the Boundary." I'm having trouble seeing why this name fits. Isn't a topological invariant a property that is not affected by homeomorphisms? What's the connection between that idea and this theorem?

Here's my attempt at a guess: A homeomorphism from one manifold with boundary to another must map interior points to interior points, and this theorem ensures that  it will map boundary points to boundary points as well.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that you are thinking of a "topological invariant" as a mathematical statement which is either true or false for any topological space, and which is preserved under homeomorphism, such as the statements "$X$ is compact" and "$X$ has seven connected components".

But there is a broader notion of a "topological invariant", which can be understood with a tiny bit of category theory: a topological invariant is a kind of function, called a "functor" in category theory, which inputs a topological space and outputs some other kind of object, such that if the inputs are homeomorphic then the outputs are isomorphisms of that other kind of object.

With that in mind, the theorem you are looking for is this:

> Let $M$ and $N$ be manifolds with boundary, and denote their boundaries as $\partial M$ and $\partial N$ and the interiors as $\text{int}(M)$ and $\text{int}(M)$. For any homeomorphism $f : M \to N$ we have $f(\partial M) = \partial N$, and $f(\text{int}(M)) = \text{int}(N)$.

The boundary operator, and the interior operator, are therefore functors whose outputs are topological spaces (as an exercise, the restricted maps $f \mid \partial M : \partial M \to \partial M$ and $f \mid \text{int}(M) : \text{int}(M) \to \text{int}(M)$ are both homeomorphisms).

I don't know how much topology you know, but here are a few other examples of topological invariants in this sense: the fundamental group; the set of connected components; the set of path components.

Comment: I'm familiar with functors, this is a really helpful way to look at it. Followup question: why is Theorem 1.37 required to prove that the boundary and interior are invariant under homeomorphisms? Isn't it still true that homeomorphisms map interiors to interiors and boundaries to boundaries even if these sets aren't necessarily disjoint?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question; the interior and boundary of a manifold are *always* disjoint. Perhaps you are confusing two uses of the word "interior"? The interior of a manifold and the interior of a subset of a topological space are two different mathematical concepts.

Comment: Right, I'm referring to the manifold boundary and manifold interior rather than the boundary and interior of a subset of a topological space. It's not immediately obvious that the boundary and interior of a manifold are disjoint; the theorem in Lee titled "Topological Invariance of the Boundary" asserts this. My question is whether or not this result is necessary to show that a manifold boundary is invariant under homeomorphism in the sense that you described in your answer.

Comment: Well, if manifold interior and manifold boundary are defined in the way I am imagining, then the theorem in my answer is sort of trivial, whereas the theorem from Lee's book in your post is more substantive. But I do not know what the definitions are from Lee's book, so I can't really answer your followup question.